# Sampling correlated clusters and calculating their weights

Tags: probability, sampling, survey-weights

In a survey I want to do I have the following problem: I have 20 clusters, and I need to choose 5. Each cluster has 10 observations, and I need to choose 2.

Lets say that the probability of choosing a cluster is uniform and independent (1/4), and the probability of choosing an observation is uniform (1/5). Then, if I want to calculate the weight of an observation (using the inverse of the probability), the weight of an observation should be 1/(0.2*0.25)=20.

Now I modify the problem and say that I can either choose clusters 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, and 16-20. The probability of choosing a cluster is still 1/4. However, in this case they are correlated... in the past probability of choosing cluster 1 AND cluster 6 was 1/16, now it is 0. However, the weighting formula will still say that, the calculation of the weights is the same as the unconditional probability of choosing A cluster is still 1/4.

Then in both cases, the weighting has to be the same.

Is this correct? Something seems very wrong.

I would like some help understanding (mathematically proving) why in both cases the weights are the same... or, if they are different, how to calculate the new weights. For me it sounds incredible that both weights are the same, as the distribution of joint probabilities are TOTALLY different in both cases.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Nick - welcome to Cross Validated. Thought experiment for you to help you on your way - what is the observations' weight if you do a Simple Random Sample (SRS) of observations of sample size $n = 10$? What is the difference between the SRS, and your initial cluster sampling problem (choose 5 clusters randomly from 20 clusters)?